# AEM Environment setup with no samplecontent, how to convert an AEM instance to no samplecontent?

Tags: aem

How can you convert an instance with sample geometrixx content into an AEM instance with nosamplecontent when it has already been setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you cannot. These are installation runmodes and they are applicable for the entire lifetime of the instance. You cannot change them once set up. Please find the excerpt from the docs

> When using one of the above run modes (author, publish, samplecontent, nosamplecontent), the value used at installation time defines the run mode for the entire lifetime of that installation.
>
> For these run modes you cannot change them after installation.